# Notas e moedas C#

Tags: c#

Estou com um erro em um algoritmo que estou implementando na linguagem c# no site do JUDGE online, [Notas e moedas](https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/1021) e eu não sei muito bem o que seja, mas acredito que seja em relação aos cálculos, dá um erro de arrendondamento, percebi isso ao colocar vários writeln, depois do cálculo, só para acompanhar as variações, com algumas entradas funciona perfeitamente. só não funciona com essa entrada 576.43 e outras. dá tudo certo, mas a última linha de saída de dados dá 2 moedas de 1c, sendo que são 3 moedas..enfim talvez tenha ficado confuso, eu não sei muito bem explicar, mas espero que os senhores entendam a minha lógica rsrs

```
using System;

class MainClass {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
    double n1,n2,n3,n4,n5,n6,m1,m2,m3,m4,m5,m6;
    double a = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    n1 = (a - a % 100)/100;
    a = a % 100;

    n2 = (a - a % 50)/50;
    a = a % 50;

    n3 = (a - a % 20)/20;
    a = a % 20;

    n4 = (a - a % 10)/10;
    a = a % 10;

    n5 = (a - a % 5)/5;
    a = a % 5;

    n6 = (a - a % 2)/2;
    a = a % 2;

    m1 = (a - a % 1)/1;
    a = a % 1;

    m2 = (a - a % 0.50)/0.50;
    a = a % 0.50;

    m3 = (a - a % 0.25)/0.25;
    a = a % 0.25;

    m4 = (a - a % 0.10)/0.10;
    a = a % 0.10;

    m5 = (a - a % 0.05)/0.05;   
    a = a % 0.05;

    m6 = (a - a % 0.01)/0.01;

    Console.WriteLine("NOTAS:");
    Console.WriteLine($"{n1} nota(s) de R$ 100.00");
    Console.WriteLine($"{n2} nota(s) de R$ 50.00");
    Console.WriteLine($"{n3} nota(s) de R$ 20.00");
    Console.WriteLine($"{n4} nota(s) de R$ 10.00");
    Console.WriteLine($"{n5} nota(s) de R$ 5.00");
    Console.WriteLine($"{n6} nota(s) de R$ 2.00");
    Console.WriteLine("MOEDAS:");
    Console.WriteLine($"{m1} moeda(s) de R$ 1.00");
    Console.WriteLine($"{m2} moeda(s) de R$ 0.50");
    Console.WriteLine($"{m3} moeda(s) de R$ 0.25");
    Console.WriteLine($"{m4} moeda(s) de R$ 0.10");
    Console.WriteLine($"{m5} moeda(s) de R$ 0.05");
    Console.WriteLine($"{m6} moeda(s) de R$ 0.01");    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos supor que o preço de um produto é R$ 4,99 e você deseja saber o valor total de 17 itens desse produto.

Abaixo, temos o código usado para fazer o cálculo usando o tipo `float` para o preço do produto e naturalmente você vai esperar o resultado de R$ 84,83 visto que 4.99×17 = 84.83. Certo?

```
float preco = 4.99f;

int quantidade = 17;

float total = preco * quantidade;

Console.WriteLine(total);

Console.ReadLine();
```

Você esperava 84,83, mas o resultado obtido foi 84,82999. Para obter o resultado correto, você deve usar o tipo `decimal`.

### Conclusão

Para qualquer cálculo que envolva dinheiro ou finanças, o tipo ***Decimal*** deve ser sempre utilizado. Só este tipo tem a precisão adequada para evitar os erros críticos de arredondamento.

Fonte: [Usando o ponto flutuante nos cálculos](https://imasters.com.br/c-sharp/c-usando-o-ponto-flutuante-nos-calculos)

Use o [sufixo](https://www.dotnetperls.com/suffix) `M` ou `m` para o tipo decimal.

```
decimal valor = 0.01m;
```

Comment: Obrigado amigo(a) pela sua resposta..mas como posso usar esse sufixo no meu caso? (se você se dispor, agradeceria um exemplo) é porque no meu programa eu to fazendo uma atribuição com cálculo, e esse exemplo ficou um pouco distante, mas vou dá uma olhada melhor como é que usa o decimal, de qualquer forma já deu uma luz!

Comment: `m2 = (a - a % 0.50m) / 0.50m;
            a = a % 0.50m;`
etc.. Mas seu código está muito repetitivo, pode usar uns arrays e ciclos para simplificar / encurtar..

Comment: Sim, é que eu ainda não aprendi..rsrs no c# não

Comment: Gostei muito da sua solução!! foi bem mais prático, obrigado mesmo!!!

Answer (score -1):

Boa noite, a sintaxe com passagem de argumentos para `Console.WriteLine()` é `Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}{2}", SUA_VAR1, SUA_VAR2, SUA_VAR3)` .... pois o metodo contem um parametro que aceita `args[]` ou seja várias variáveis.

```
Console.WriteLine($"{m6} moeda(s) de R$ 0.01");
```

Remova o `$`, já  o `{m6}` deve ser sua variável de index 0 `{0}`. Coloque uma virgula ao final e passe os argumentos a função.

Quando você quer fazer operações matemáticas com duas casas decimais como por exemplo em moedas você deve fazer um arrendondamento pois o `MOD` ou no caso `%` usando `double` tem  valores muito grandes 64 bits que não necessitamos no caso, use o `Math.Round()` pra arredonda um valor para o inteiro mais próximo ou para o número especificado de casas decimais. Há e você não precisa calcular o m6 pois já é o resto do valor em si.

Exemplo:

```
    int n1,n2,n3,n4,n5,n6,m1,m2,m3,m4,m5,m6;
    double a = 576.43f;
    a = Math.Round(a, 2);

    n1 = (int)(a - a % 100)/100;
    a = Math.Round(a % 100, 2);
    n2 = (int)(a - a % 50)/50;
    a = Math.Round(a % 50, 2);
    n3 = (int)(a - a % 20)/20;
    a = Math.Round(a % 20, 2);
    n4 = (int)(a - a % 10)/10;
    a = Math.Round(a % 10, 2);
    n5 = (int)(a - a % 5)/5;
    a = Math.Round(a % 5, 2);
    n6 = (int)(a - a % 2)/2;
    a = Math.Round(a % 2, 2);
    m1 = (int)(a - a % 1)/1;
    a = Math.Round(a % 1, 2);
    m2 = Convert.ToInt32((a - a % 0.50)/0.50);
    a = Math.Round(a % 0.50, 2);
    m3 = Convert.ToInt32((a - a % 0.25)/0.25);
    a = Math.Round(a % 0.25, 2);
    m4 = Convert.ToInt32((a - a % 0.10)/0.10);
    a = Math.Round(a % 0.10, 2);
    m5 = Convert.ToInt32((a - a % 0.05)/0.05);   
    a = Math.Round(a % 0.05, 2);
    m6 = Convert.ToInt32(a/0.01);

    Console.WriteLine("NOTAS:");
    Console.WriteLine("{0} nota(s) de R$ 100.00", n1);
    Console.WriteLine("{0} nota(s) de R$ 50.00", n2);
    Console.WriteLine("{0} nota(s) de R$ 20.00", n3);
    Console.WriteLine("{0} nota(s) de R$ 10.00", n4);
    Console.WriteLine("{0} nota(s) de R$ 5.00", n5);
    Console.WriteLine("{0} nota(s) de R$ 2.00", n6);
    Console.WriteLine("MOEDAS:");
    Console.WriteLine("{0} moeda(s) de R$ 1.00", m1);
    Console.WriteLine("{0} moeda(s) de R$ 0.50", m2);
    Console.WriteLine("{0} moeda(s) de R$ 0.25", m3);
    Console.WriteLine("{0} moeda(s) de R$ 0.10", m4);
    Console.WriteLine("{0} moeda(s) de R$ 0.05", m5);
    Console.WriteLine("{0} moeda(s) de R$ 0.01", m6);
```

Comment: Obrigado amigo! porém, não resolveu o meu problema ainda. :/ continua com o mesmo problema;

Comment: Eu acho que seja um problema com o arrendondamento na terceira variável (n3)ele atribui um número cheio de números depois da vírgula, um exemplo é se eu colocar 576.43 na entrada, deveria recebe-lá 6.43, mas quando chega ai acontece algo miraculoso que eu não entendi e atribui 6.4999999992 algo assim, saca? é por isso que dá erro, eu acho;

Comment: Não tinha visto esse detalhe, você deve usar o Math.Round() para arredondamento, de uma olhada na minha resposta novamente.

Comment: Parece que deu certo! não sei se o uri online vai aceitar ainda rsrs eu tinha tentado usar o comando math round, mas não havia conseguido.. muito obrigado!

Comment: Deu certo, fera!(em referência que o site aceitou também) ksks